# Making a td contract to only it's padding and content

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I've got a table arranged like this:

```
<table style="width:100%" class="ui-widget-content">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="width:100px;padding:10px">
        </td>
        <td style="padding:5px">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want it to look like this when filled with some content (Sorry for bad ASCII art):

```
-----------------------
|     |               |
|     |---------------|
|     |               |
|     |               |
|     |               |
-----------------------
```

However it looks like this:

```
-----------------------
|     |               |
|     |               |
|     | --------------|
|     |               |
|     |               |
-----------------------
```

I did do height:1% in top one but it doesn't work in IE, so I'm looking for a less haxxy approach.

Any advice?

Edit:

Here's the actual code I'm using with the PHP left in:

```
<table style="width:100%" class="ui-widget-content">
    <tr style="height:1px">
        <td class="ui-widget-header" rowspan="2" style="width:100px;padding:10px">
            <?= "<img src='/userPictures/$img.png' style='width:100%;height:100%'/>" ?>
        </td>
        <td class="ui-widget-header" style="padding:5px">
            <?= $profileDetails['name']; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?= stripslashes($wP['Text']); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `height` on the `tr`.

Try this

```
table{
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

tr{
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

tr.top{
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

tr td{
    border:1px solid red;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/U3JYX/

Comment: Same problem as other answer unfortunately. I added an image to the left cell, and the top right cell just stretched randomly. I clicked run but I've never used jsFiddle so I don't know if it saves for everyone or just me.

Comment: To save with jsfiddle, click update.  The URL will be updated and you can share that with us.  As for the issues with the image, try to change the `height` in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="height:100%;"` to the bottom row (`tr` tag).

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    table tr td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    table {
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%" class="ui-widget-content">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width:100px; padding:10px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="padding:5px;">Some text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:100%;">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem unfortunately. Identical results. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: You do need to set width of html, body and table itself. It definitely gives the result you're looking for. I've updated the answer to give you full code. Idefinitely tested it.

Comment: It's in a div with a set width (Edit: I'm using Firefox and IE9, it didn't show in either. Are you using Google Chrome?)

Comment: Wait, it's working like it's meant to when I take the image out of the left container. When I put an image in the left container, it stretched the top one? I think that'd be the rowspan messing it up somehow? (Edit: Yeah I just did a literal copy/paste of your code, added an image, and it stretched top cell.)